# MvvmCross updates to bound property in View not propagating to property in ViewModel

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I'm trying to bind a (non-component) property in my View to a property in my View Model. Here is the simplified code.

View:

```
public partial class InputFormCell : MvxTableViewCell
{
    [Outlet]
    UIKit.UITextField Text {get; set;}

    public bool SelectOnFocus {get; set;}
    public bool TextHasFocus {get; set;}

    public InputFormCell(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
        this.DelayBind(() =>
        {
            this.Text.EditingDidBegin += (sender, e) =>
            {
                this.BecomeFirstResponder();
                if(SelectOnFocus)
                {
                    Text.PerformSelector(new Selector("selectAll"), null, 0.0f);
                }

                TextHasFocus = true;
            };

            this.Text.EditingDidEnd += (sender, e) => 
            {
                TextHasFocus = false;
            };

            var set = this.CreateBindingSet<InputFormCell, InputViewModel>();
            set.Bind(Text).To(vm => vm.Text);
            set.Bind(this).For(vc => vc.TextHasFocus).To(vm => vm.TextHasFocus).TwoWay();
            set.Apply();
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
[ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class InputViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    public string Text {get; set;}
    public event Action<string> TextGetsFocus;

    public bool TextHasFocus { get; set; }
    protected virtual void OnTextHasFocusChanged()
    {
        if (TextHasFocus) // Problem: Never gets to here.
        {
            TextGetsFocus?.Invoke(Text);
        }

        // ..
    }
}
```

The `ImplementPropertyChanged` attribute is part of Fody (I think), but in any case, `OnTextHasFocusChanged` gets triggered correctly when `InputViewModel.TextHasFocus` is updated directly. But it doesn't get triggered through this binding I have in place.

Question: Why doesn't `OnTextHasFocusChanged` trigger when `InputFormCell.TextHasFocus` is updated?

Comment: Because `TextHasFocus` in `InputFormCell` is a simple property and is not raising a change event. Mvx data binding seems like magic, but it is simply listening for events to trigger the binding. Things like `Text` and `Button Click` etc have default bindings. You either need to create a custom binding for the Focus event, or just set the VM.TextHasFocus property directly.

Comment: Looks like Mvx has a binding for getting Text value when focus ends. You can look at the implementation to create one for when focus begins. https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/f9f6e2643d2defc6ccc033f899a8ecf599441e67/MvvmCross/Binding/iOS/Target/MvxUITextFieldTextFocusTargetBinding.cs

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for that. I'd avoid setting VM.TextHasFocus directly, as this breaks MVVM principles. I'll look at the implementation you refer to, and see how much work is involved in creating my own custom binding.

Comment: Not every interaction has to be done with data-binding. It's Ok for the View to talk to the ViewModel. That's the role of the VM... to support the View. Yes, it's nice when you can do it declaratively through binding statements, but that's not always possible. For example, in Android, there's no binding support for mapping Menu items (resource ids) to VM Commands. You basically need a switch statement in `OnOptionsItemSelected`.

Comment: I thought the whole point of MVVM was to overcome tight coupling between View and VM, as a means to improve (things like refactorability, testability, the whole shebang) over other variations such as MVC/MVP? And it did that by way of bindings? So, if you don't use bindings, you might as well not use MVVM, since you are not using it for its...main thing that it's meant for? Or am I mistaken? Thanks for your input.

Comment: All the things you mention don't go away just because the View interacts with the ViewModel. Why do you think there's a one-to-one mapping between View and VM? The View allows you to separate the platform UI from the shared logic in the VM. You can get/set properties, call methods, commands, etc. from the View. There are also times I need to call some platform-specific method from the VM. Sometimes I'll create a plugin, but most of the time, I'll simply add an Action property on the VM that the View sets, and the VM calls as needed. Anyway, there is no right or wrong way to do things.